# Shopware 6 delete specific files from vendor

Tags: shopware, shopware6

When I run build-administration I get the following error during the step "Calling reporter service for single check."

> ERROR in unable to locate '/var/www/vendor/store.shopware.com/netinexteasycoupondesigns/src/Resources/app/administration/static/**/*' glob

The vendor of the plugin recommended to delete the path `src/Resources/app` inside the plugins source files. Since they're installed via composer I'm not able to delete these files persistently e.g. on production or other environments.

How can I persist these changes? With a composer patch, or is there any other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### WARNING: This does not work as intended

This answer is probably invalid, we are investigating, but using this method, some important parts seem to be missing from the build.

I let this answer stand as a warning an hope, someone will provide a better answer

---

Original answer:

We assume you have certain 3rd party plugins which don't need to be built, as well as some own project specific plugins which need building.

If we take a look [build-administration.sh](https://github.com/shopware/production/blob/40e5c0f40fd4a72f3a497b2b163b95a52ceebc40/bin/build-administration.sh#L21), it normally executed `bundle:dump` which would write the `var/plugin.json` which determined which packages to build in the build process.
The file is usually not committed to the git repository.

##### Do not build 3rd party dependencies

The following approach would work to avoid building 3rd party dependencies.

- Add `var/plugins.json` to the git
- Remove all non-custom modules from `plugins.json`
- Call `SHOPWARE_SKIP_BUNDLE_DUMP=1 bin/build-administration.sh` to avoid rebuilding the `plugins.json`

You have to remember to add new custom plugins manually to the file. Probably the easiest way is to call `bundle:dump` again then remove the 3rd party modules.

Another option might be to generate the `plugins.json` before the build using `bundle:dump` and then filter the file using `jq`. But I did not test this.

Depending on the number of plugins, this will also speed up the build process.

Answer (score 3):

That plugin has [additional NPM dependencies](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/using-npm-dependencies) that it relies on in the build process. I tried running `npm clean-install` in `custom/plugins/NetiNextEasyCouponDesigns/src/Resources/app/administration/` but it still wouldn't compile afterwards. I assume you don't have to actually recompile this plugins assets. Unless the developer of the plugin fixes the issue, building the administration will fail in one way or another.

If you have a pipeline that runs composer und builds the administration, I would recommend to simply require this plugin after the administration has been built. Since plugins come with pre-built assets, there most often is no reason to rebuild them.

Another simple way to exclude this plugin from building is to deactivate it before starting the build...

```bash
bin/console plugin:deactivate NetiNextEasyCouponDesigns
```

...and then afterwards activate it again:

```bash
bin/console plugin:activate NetiNextEasyCouponDesigns
```

Comment: So in the end of the day, the plugin developer should fix the issue, right? Do you know what's the problem with the plugin? In the end of the day workarounds should be avoided I would say. Maybe build-administration should have a switch to only build plugins in custom/ - this would also speed up the process.

Comment: Turns out there is some way, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

w´re aware of the problem, but there is no satisfying solution because shopware forces us to ship the uncompiled source files in our plugins

**In most cases the deployment doesnt work because you use an outdated version of NodeJs and NPM.**

So please make sure you have the lastest **NPM LTS** Version installed - **NodeJS 12** is outdated - use the latest like **NodeJS 16 and NPM 8.x**

If it's not possible to update NodeJs and NPM there are two options:

**Option 1**

- deactivate our plugin: `bin/console plugin:deactivate NetiNextEasyCouponDesigns`
- build administration:
  `bin/build-administration.sh`
- activate our plugin: `bin/console plugin:activate NetiNextEasyCouponDesigns`

**Option 2**

- remove directory: `NetiNextEasyCouponDesigns/src/Resources/app/administration`
- build administration: `bin/build-administration.sh`

Comment: We are on node v16.17.0 / npm 8.15.0 still it does not work - we might try the Option 2, but it is still a workaround

Comment: Do you mean to delete the folder vendor/store.shopware.com/netinexteasycoupondesigns/src/Resources/app/ ? There are lots of files in there .. for example translations are not found anymore after deleting that folder.

Comment: Its save to remove the NetiNextEasyCouponDesigns/src/Resources/app/administration folder. Our compiled JS file is located: "NetiNextEasyCouponDesigns/src/Resources/public/administration/js/neti-next-easy-coupon-designs.js" and this file will be included.

Comment: Oh, okay, the original answer said NetiNextEasyCouponDesigns/src/Resources/app/ - thank you for the correction